# correspondance between sql server data and poco class in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am developping an asp.net mvc application where I can handle some objects stored in my sql server db. I have a table called "user" with a field "name" declared like this :

```
name NVARCHAR(250).
```

Now I would like to know how to declare in my poco class "user" the dataannotation on the attribute name to not exceed the capacity of the field in my db.

I have already this :

```
[Required]
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

Thanks in advance for  your help

Comment: you can use `[StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Name Max Length is 250")]`

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry if the question seems stupid, but I would like to know if the 250 parameters correspond to the maximum number of characters in this field ?

Comment: Correct because you define your name as `nvarchar(250)`, you can choose which amount you like

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are able to use something like this

`[StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Name Max Length is 250")]`